# How do I limit a number between two numbers in java

Tags: calculation

I need to define a number between *n*, such that `999<n<9999`, and I'm not sure how to do that.

I've tried to make an `If` situation out of it, but I couldn't reach further because my `number` is not defined. Also this is for a Java package.

Comment: Please add some code... And read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you looking for the generation of a random number in that range? what do you mean, in - *my number is not defined*? why don't you define if you need it? it's unclear what you're asking. Please be more specific.

Comment: Ok, *n* = 1235.  Seriously, besides your lower and upper limit, what are the criteria for determining *n*?

Comment: For example, my number would be inserted in my input so that my java can tell me how many decimals that my given number has, if I put in as answer 4859 it will tell me that I have 4 thousands, 8 hundreds, 5 tens and 9 units. But I require to make the number that I will put - a number that I can change when I run my code, stay between a range of to 999 to 9999.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I generate random integers within a specific range in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/how-do-i-generate-random-integers-within-a-specific-range-in-java)